# how to bind database value in dropdown?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

i am working on a project in which i have to show values coming from database, in drop down and then filter the record based on choosed option.
i am stucked in the very first step, i tried to create a logic to show the values in dropdown in multiple ways but its not working i am not sure if i am doing it in a write way,

here is my code:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/web/GetFilterRecords")]
        public List<DocumentMaster> GetFilterRecords()
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                List<DocumentMaster> xx = db.Documents.Where(x => x.VoucherYear.Contains(x.VoucherYear)).Select(p => new DocumentMaster()
                {
                    VoucherYear = p.VoucherYear,
                    YEAR = p.VoucherYear,
                }).ToList();
                return xx;
            }
        }
```

```
<div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="">Select Voucher Year</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                   
         <select2 v-model="vm.V_Year" class="form-control">
                                <option v-for="option in Year" v-bind:value="option.years">{{option.YEAR}}</option>
                            </select2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```
var vueContent = new Vue({
            el: '#Form',
            data: {
                vm: {
                    voucherid: null,
                    V_Year: null,
                     },
                    Year: [{ years: null, YEAR: "select year" }],
            },
            watch: {
                'vm.fromdate': function () {
                'vm.V_Year': function () {
                    axios.get("/api/web/GetFilterRecords?year=" + this.vm.V_Year).then((res) => {
                        this.Year = res.data;
                    });
                  },
```

Comment: Please also provide some debugging information. There's a lot of places where something can go wrong that we can't tell from just code.  Does your frontend call actually make it to your backend (i.e. if you put a breakpoint in your code, does it get hit)? Before your API endpoint executes `return xx`, have you determined if `xx` is the expected data?  On the frontend did you console.log the result `res` or `res.data` of your axios call and verify it matches the correct format expected by your template code?

Comment: no point gets hit while placing a breakpoint in code

Comment: if the backend isn't receiving any request, then that should help you really narrow down where the problem is.  either your frontend is trying to send a request to the wrong URL or you've misunderstood what the actual URL is to your endpoint.